# Replace placeholders from a file in another file

Tags: java, python, regex

I am trying to create a utility which would:

1. Extract placeholder from a `.plh` file placed on the file system.
2. Create a hash map through the delimited key-value pairs.
3. Replace the key from value throughout the file.
4. Write the output file on the file-system.

I am able to create the hash-map, using Python and Java. I am confused about what approach to follow for the string replacement part. Is there something similar to `sed -i [regex]` in both of these languages?

Below is the code that I have written:

```
public class PlaceHolderReplace
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<String,String>();
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                InputStream input = null;
                InputStream msg= null;
                String msgString= null;
                try
                {
                        input = new FileInputStream("placeholders.plh");
                        msg= new FileInputStream("test.xml");
                        prop.load(input);
                        Enumeration e = prop.propertyNames();
                        while(e.hasMoreElements())
                        {
                                String key = (String)e.nextElement();
                                map.put(key,prop.getProperty(key));
                        }
                        for(String key:map.keySet())
                        {
                                //System.out.println("Key ="+key+", value ="+map.get(key));

                        }
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
if(input != null)
                        {
                                try
                                {
                                        input.close();
                                }
                                catch(IOException e)
                                {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you implementing this yourself, rather than using some existing templating engine?

Comment: I have to make it running at my work-PC. We are not allowed to download third-party jars, unless approved by our supervisors, which takes a long time.

Comment: Wait. So you're actually *forbidden* to follow good practice by your employer?

Comment: Is the language mandatory or is the question: How could I do a template system with the availability of java, python, [other ?] on <this OS> ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. 
@o11c its for security reasons.

Comment: @Tensibai Language isn't mandatory, but preferable, because I have worked with both of these languages.

Comment: I would do a basic 'global' replace in msg at each prop iteration instead of making the hash... It's just an idea on the table

Comment: Yes, global replace is what I want(point 3 in my description). I just wanted to know how it can be done, and also the most efficient way to do it(because the message templates are huge XML files in our usage scenario).Should I convert the complete XML into string, and then use replaceAll()? Also how can I replace multiple patterns in one go? (Similar to sed -i in unix)

Comment: @Manas okay, is there any reason you *can't* just use `sed -i` (although I do question your use of in-place editing). I've frequently emitted a bunch of `s///` lines and then used `sed -f` to load them

Comment: @o11c Of-course I can use sed(In fact I want to use it), but will it be cross-platform? Some sample code would be helpful, especially for my scenario.

Comment: @Manas A basic file containing just `s///g` lines is portable; anything else probably isn't. Just remember to escape `/` as well as special characters when writing out your regex